# Why does this css generate a yellow paragraph

Tags: html, css

```
        <style>
    p {
        color:         red;
    }
    .warm {
        color:         green;
    }
    p.warm {
        color:         orange;
    }
    p.cute {
        color:         yellow;
    }
    p.boring {
        color:         blue;
    }
    }

    </style>

<p class="warm cute boring">
```

I was expecting this to give a blue color to the code. Can you explain why?

Comment: The `}` at the end should be before `p.boring`. Typo.

Comment: Thanks it was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You're not closing your `p.cute` rule properly.

```
p.cute {
    color:         yellow;

p.boring {
    color:         blue;
}
}
```

should be

```
p.cute {
    color:         yellow;

}
p.boring {
    color:         blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i fixed that. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a valid css, because you can't nest rules in CSS.

The `p.boring` rule, due to that, is ignored.

Comment: In the above example i had a typo. I fixed that but still i get a yellow colored paragraph not a blue one.